# discord.js error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i have a problem with discord bot. I just triing to get it working, but i cannot figure out where this error is.

```
const {discord,  Intents} = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.client();

client.on('ready', () => {
     console.log(client.user.tag);
});

client.login("token");
```

This is my entire code without package.json

Error message looks like this: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods you are using seem to be deprecated on Discord.js v13 and posterior.

You could instead use:

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });

client.on('ready', () => {
     console.log('We are up!');
});

client.login(process.env.SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN);
```

If you need help moving your entire codebase to Discord.js v13 or v14, you can always check the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome) and the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Where did you got number 32763?

Comment: @Komiš that is great! Intent 32763 is just a shortcut to indicate that your Bot has all intents that the Discord API can provide. You can read more about this on the [official guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) :)

Comment: @SebastiánCamargo it is highly unrecommended to use *32767* intents. It completely defeats the purpose of intents, makes your bot slower, and actually doesn't use all the intents...